# Форматирование чисел добавить пробелы между разрядами до точки или запятой

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, числа

Регулярное выражение должно форматировать числа по принципу:

1000,999 -> 1 000,999

10000.99 -> 10 000.99

1000000 -> 1 000 000

```
function format(value) { ... }
```

Comment: Вы хотите добавить пробелы между разрядами до точки или запятой?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew да

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример для ES6+:

```js
let strs = ['1000,999', '10000.99', '1000000'];
for (var s of strs) {
  let [_, num, suffix] = s.match(/^(.*?)((?:[,.]\d+)?|)$/);
  console.log(`${num.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})*$)/g, ' ')}${suffix}`);
} // -> 1 000,999 , 10 000.99 , 1 000 000
```

Пример для ES5:

```js
var strs = ['1000,999', '10000.99', '1000000'];
for (var i=0; i<strs.length; i++) {
  var m = strs[i].match(/^(.*?)((?:[,.]\d+)?|)$/);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})*$)/g, ' ') + m[2]);
  } else {
    console.log(strs[i]);
  }
} // -> 1 000,999 , 10 000.99 , 1 000 000
```

Смысл в том, чтобы отделить часть до точки или запятой и после, вставить пробелы в первой части,  а потом их объединить.

**Подробности**

- `^(.*?)((?:[,.]\d+)?|)$`:

  - `^` - начало строки
  - `(.*?)` - Подмаска №1: 0 и более любых символов (можно заменить на `(\d*)` для захвата только цифр)
  - `((?:[,.]\d+)?|)` - Подмаска №2: точка или запятая, а потом 1+ цифр или пустая строка
  - `$` - конец строки

`replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})*$)/g, ' ')` вставляет 1 пробел в том месте, сразу после которого идёт 0 и более повторов 3 цифр до конца строки.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант без регулярки:**

Это делается через Intl.NumberFormat - Вот тут есть [дока](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

С точкой тоже работает из коробки :) Для запятой придется поковыряться, сделаем `.replace(',', '.')` , и в случаи если нужно вернуть обратно знак который был, еще раз `.replace('.', ',')`

Примерчик:

```js
function format(value) {
  let res;
  
  (value.indexOf(',') != -1) ? res = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(value.replace(',', '.')).replace('.', ',') : res = new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format(value).replace(',', '.');
  
  return res;
}

console.log(format('12312312,123'));
console.log(format('12312312.123'));
console.log(format('12312312'));
```

Comment: `console.log( new Intl.NumberFormat('ru-RU').format('1000,999') );` выводит `не число`

Comment: Вы правы. отредактировал свой пример, чтобы он работал как с точкой, так и с запятой.

Comment: `10000.99` => `10 000,99`, а нужно `10 000.99`

Comment: Согласен. Поправил еще раз, чтобы он возвращал изначальный знак.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, можно ли начать replace с конца строки... поэтому попробовал такой вариант:

```js
var a = "1000,999"
var b = 10000.99;
var c = -1000000;


function bubu(a){
  var point = "";
  //Пока удаляю, но сохраняю целую часть...
  var x = String(a).replace(/(\.|,)\d+/, function(m){ point = m; return ""; });
  
  x = x.split("").reverse().join("")
       .replace(/(\d{3})/g,"$1 ")
       .split("").reverse().join("");
  //Разбил в массив, перевернул, расставил пробелы, перевернул обратно.
  return x + point;
}

console.log( bubu(a) );
console.log( bubu(b) );
console.log( bubu(c) );
```